# Push an argument into stack?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm

I know that the first four arguments are in the register (`RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, `R9`), and that additional arguments are pushed on the stack.

### Question:

How to push an argument onto the stack? I tried with (push 0) but it does not work?

**Code** (*MASM64*)

```
extrn ExitProcess: PROC   
extrn MessageBoxExA: PROC
.data
caption db '64-bit hello!', 0
message db 'Hello World!', 0
.code
Start PROC
  sub    rsp, 38h        
  mov    rcx, 0         ; hWnd = HWND_DESKTOP
  lea    rdx, message   ; LPCSTR lpText
  lea    r8,  caption   ; LPCSTR lpCaption
  mov    r9d, 0         ; uType = MB_OK

  push   0          ; wLanguageId

  call   MessageBoxExA  
  mov    ecx, eax       
  add    rsp, 38h
  call ExitProcess
Start ENDP
End
```

I'm know that `MessageBox` and `MessageBoxEx` work the same way, but im trying to use `MessageBoxEx` because its need one parameter to be passed (for learning purpose).

*I know I've asked similar question, but it is more related to vb.net while this is not.*

Comment: I think you've subtracted too much from rsp. Try `sub rsp, 20h` instead. The reason is the caller needs to allocate "register home (or spill) space" on the stack for the 4 registers (rcx,rdx,r8,r9) which is 4 * 8 = 0n32 = 0x20. The 5th (and subsequent args) appear just after this space so that's why I suggest subtracting only 0x20 bytes from rsp instead of 0x38.

Comment: The Windows ABI does not permit the stack pointer to change during a function execution (at least not without doing extra work), and you are changing it twice (once with the push and once with the add outside the epilogue), your function lacks a proper prologue declaration, and you are putting the fifth parameter on the stack on the wrong place. I think the easiest solution is to just write the program in C then look at what the compiler generated.

Comment: you need to be carefull with that so called shadow space.  I've implemented two subroutines in a simple windows application. One for MessageBoxA and another for ShellAboutA.(dialogbox).  Although I read everywhere that a shadow space of 20h is required for both, the MessageBox needs 28h shadowspace. Seems normal because 4x8 bytes for rcx, rdx, r8 and r9 plus the additional return address to caller on stack.  I used the same logic for ShellAbout. Also 4 x 8 + 8 for the return address and that part of the application crashes. It only need 4 x 8 bytes shadow space. To much nor to less is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assembly is a little rusty, but I was under the impression that all arguments went onto the stack (in reverse order) - I'd have thought you want to be pushing r8 and rdx in as well as the other arguments. Frankly though you might as well just keep doing `lea rax, param` and `push rax` for each of the arguments that are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the arguments are passed and whether they are passed in registers or on the stack (along with whether caller or callee is responsible for cleanup) is defined by the 'Calling Convention'.

What you are probably thinking of is STDCALL or CDECL, both are calling conventions used in 32-bit Windows that pass arguments on the stack in reverse order (right to left). x64 has moved to a FastCall calling convention where the arguments are passed in forward order (from left to right) and the first 4 arguments are passed in the registers RCX, RDX, R8 & R9. Any arguments beyond 4 are passed on the stack in the same left-to-right order. The original poster had the correct calling convention setup for x64 assembly with MASM. Also, the above responder who said the shadowspace valued subtracted from RSP should be 20h (32d) is correct. The shadow space is allowing space on the stack for the 4 arguments that are passed in by the registers in FastCall.

Changing the code above to:

```
extrn ExitProcess: PROC   
extrn MessageBoxExA: PROC
.data
caption db '64-bit hello!', 0
message db 'Hello World!', 0
.code

Start PROC
  sub    rsp, 20h        
  mov    rcx, 0         ; hWnd = HWND_DESKTOP
  lea    rdx, message   ; LPCSTR lpText
  lea    r8,  caption   ; LPCSTR lpCaption
  mov    r9d, 0         ; uType = MB_OK

  push   0          ; wLanguageId

  call   MessageBoxExA  
  mov    ecx, eax       
  add    rsp, 20h
  call ExitProcess
Start ENDP
End
```

Works just fine in Visual Studio on a 64-bit machine

Comment: Try it with ShellAbout. 4 registers. Put it in a subroutine and you will see that it will work your way. With MessageBoxA in a subroutine my application crashes. I wonder why. Perhaps inconsistent coding from microsoft ? I'm still looking